# Extracting json values using a key

Tags: r, json, jsonlite, rjsonio

I have a JSON string called `test` in which some elements contain more than one key (for example, foo and bar).

My goal is to only extract the values of `foo`.  How can one do this with R?

I have tried converting to both matrix and data.frame but this does not help solve the issue.

```
> test
[1] "{\"foo\":[1,2,3],\"bar\":[0]}" "{\"foo\":[1]}"                 "{\"foo\":[4], \"bar\":[1]}"   
[4] "{\"foo\":[2]}"                 "{\"foo\":[1,2]}"               "{\"foo\":[3]}"
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
dput(test)
c("{\"foo\":[1,2,3],\"bar\":[0]}", "{\"foo\":[1]}", "{\"foo\":[4], \"bar\":[1]}", 
"{\"foo\":[2]}", "{\"foo\":[1,2]}", "{\"foo\":[3]}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `fromJSON` to convert to a data.frame and then extract the `foo` column which is a `list` column

```
library(jsonlite)
lapply(paste0("[", test, "]"), function(x) unlist(fromJSON(x)$foo))
```

---

Or `paste` the elements into a single string and then do the `fromJSON`

```
fromJSON(paste0("[", paste(test, collapse=","), "]"))$foo
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1

#[[3]]
#[1] 4

#[[4]]
#[1] 2

#[[5]]
#[1] 1 2

#[[6]]
#[1] 3
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
str_c(test, collapse=",") %>%
    str_c("[", ., "]") %>%
    fromJSON %>%
    pull(foo)
```